# How to avoid KDE disabling external monitor on suspend?

Tags: debian, kde, display, kde5

I noticed that when I suspend my laptop running KDE, the external monitor gets marked as disabled in the settings. I need to enable it after resuming the system (in system settings for displays). How can I avoid it? Is it a bug?

```
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.97.0
Qt Version: 5.15.4
Kernel Version: 5.18.16-1rodete1-amd64 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz
Memory: 15.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Product Name: 20XXS3LB1K
System Version: ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 9
```

Comment: On my Debian11/KDE system the session is quit [when I connect another monitor with HDMI](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=457755) or when [waking from standby with it connected](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1018003). Maybe this is related but you're probably not also using Wayland. For me the monitor disappears from the display settings when disconnected.

Comment: Does `xrandr --auto` reactivate the monitor?

Comment: @FelixJN, it does, however it mirrors the display - which is not quite what I want.